# Calculate the expected value from the characteristic function?

Tags: probability

We consider the random variables (real) $(X,Y)$ such as :

$\Phi_{(X,Y)}(s) = \mathbb{E}[\exp(isX+itY)] = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} \exp(-\dfrac{s^2}{2(1+t^2)})$.

I have calculated $\Phi_X(s) = \exp(\dfrac{-s^2}{2})$ which is the characteristic function of a Gaussian with $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$ and $o^2(X) = 1$ (standard deviation).

And $\Phi_Y(t) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$. I have to calculate the expected value and the variance of $Y$. How calculate this values from the characteristic function ? Thank you in advance (and sorry for my bad english).

Comment: $\operatorname{E}[X^k] = (-i)^k \varphi_X^{(k)}(0)$  assuming the derivatives exist

Comment: Thank you, I find $\mathbb{E}(Y) = 0$. Do you know a similar formula for the variance or should another method be used ?

Comment: The standard method would be to take the second derivative, evaluate it at $0$, multiply by $(-i)^2$, and subtract the square of the mean.